# Trouble with urllib2 in Django Views

Tags: json, django, python-2.7, django-views, urllib2

I'm trying to read a website using urllib2, convert the text to a json object and then pass it to my views.py file.  The function works when I run it separately, but it gives me an empty json object when I import the function into my views.py file.

Here's a sample of my code:
    import urllib2
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    import json

```
def query_incidents():

    my_url = 'https://mywebsite.com'

    url_request = urllib2.Request(my_url)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url_request)

    query_string = response.read()

    query_json = json.loads(query_string)

    response.close()

    print query_json
```

Here's an example of what is returned when I run my code:

```
[
{u'latitude': u'47.635873', u'longitude': u'-122.325586', u'datetime': 1471218540}, 
{u'latitude': u'47.724362', u'longitude': u'-122.282826', u'datetime': 1471218720}, 
{u'latitude': u'47.710811', u'longitude': u'-122.281078', u'datetime': 1471218840}, 
{u'latitude': u'47.689113', u'longitude': u'-122.355301', u'datetime': 1471218960}, 
{u'latitude': u'47.659960', u'longitude': u'-122.342217', u'datetime': 1471219140}, 
{u'latitude': u'47.569608', u'longitude': u'-122.290486', u'datetime': 1471219260}, 
{u'latitude': u'47.731040', u'longitude': u'-122.347764', u'datetime': 1471219500}
]
```

When I try to import my code into views.py, I get:

```
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps...

```
def query_incidents():

    my_url = 'https://mywebsite.com'

    url_request = urllib2.Request(my_url)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url_request)

    query_string = response.read()

    query_json = json.loads(query_string)

    response.close()
    return query_string
```

Then call the query_incidents() returned value in your views.py
For example let's say you have a function defined in your views.py called make_file(arg) you would call the query_incidents() function in the arg which returns the data to your views.py

Comment: So I'm calling my function query_incidents() in my views.py and it's still returning [ ] .  Any other suggestions?